# PHP PostGIS to GeoJSON missing required parameter error

Tags: postgis, geojson, php

I'm using this PHP PostGIS to geoJSON script: https://gist.github.com/bmcbride/1913855

But I keep getting this error: `'missing required parameter: geotable'`

This is my code:

```
  # Retrive URL variables
    if (empty($_GET['WTGs_All'])) {
        echo "missing required parameter: <i>geotable</i>";
        exit;
    } else
        $geotable = $_GET['WTGs_All'];

    if (empty($_GET['the_geom'])) {
        echo "missing required parameter: <i>geomfield</i>";
        exit;
    } else
        $geomfield = $_GET['the_geom'];

    if (empty($_GET['srid'])) {
        $srid = '4326';
    } else
        $srid = $_GET['srid'];

    if (empty($_GET['fields'])) {
        $fields = '*';
    } else
        $fields = $_GET['fields'];

    $parameters = $_GET['parameters'];

    $orderby    = $_GET['orderby'];

    if (empty($_GET['sort'])) {
        $sort = 'ASC';
    } else
        $sort = $_GET['sort'];

    $limit      = $_GET['limit'];

    $offset     = $_GET['offset'];

    # Connect to PostgreSQL database
    $conn = pg_connect("dbname='postgres' user='postgres' password='****' port='5432' host='localhost'");
    if (!$conn) {
        echo "Not connected : " . pg_error();
        exit;
    }
# Build SQL SELECT statement and return the geometry as a GeoJSON element in EPSG: 4326
$sql = "SELECT " . pg_escape_string($fields) . ", st_asgeojson(transform(" . pg_escape_string($geomfield) . ",$srid)) AS geojson FROM " . pg_escape_string($geotable);
if (strlen(trim($parameters)) > 0) {
    $sql .= " WHERE " . pg_escape_string($parameters);
}
if (strlen(trim($orderby)) > 0) {
    $sql .= " ORDER BY " . pg_escape_string($orderby) . " " . $sort;
}
if (strlen(trim($limit)) > 0) {
    $sql .= " LIMIT " . pg_escape_string($limit);
}
if (strlen(trim($offset)) > 0) {
    $sql .= " OFFSET " . pg_escape_string($offset);
}
//echo $sql;

# Try query or error
$rs = pg_query($conn, $sql);
if (!$rs) {
    echo "An SQL error occured.\n";
    exit;
}

# Build GeoJSON
$output    = '';
$rowOutput = '';

while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $rowOutput = (strlen($rowOutput) > 0 ? ',' : '') . '{"type": "Feature", "geometry": ' . $row['geojson'] . ', "properties": {';
    $props = '';
    $id    = '';
    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
        if ($key != "geojson") {
            $props .= (strlen($props) > 0 ? ',' : '') . '"' . $key . '":"' . escapeJsonString($val) . '"';
        }
        if ($key == "id") {
            $id .= ',"id":"' . escapeJsonString($val) . '"';
        }
    }

    $rowOutput .= $props . '}';
    $rowOutput .= $id;
    $rowOutput .= '}';
    $output .= $rowOutput;
}

$output = '{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [ ' . $output . ' ]}';
echo $output;
?>
```

My table is called `WTGs_All`, I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Are you passing a `WTGs_All` parameter in your get request? if so, what is it?

Comment: Hm, I'm new with PHP so I'm not sure what you're thinking about. I put all code now so please check it out. Maybe I'm using this code in a wrong way. Thanks.

Comment: This php script is a service. You need to pass in parameters and you will get the results according to the parameters. Without these parameters, you will get the error that you are seeing.

Comment: Can you explain me a little bit more how can I do that? I need to convert postgis data to geojson so I can add it to Leaflet map. I worked with Leaflet hundred times but didn't work with postgis data when working with Leaflet. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not know much of Php, I would suggest that you use the original Php script. Do not change anything except for the connection parameters on the Line 61. Then place the postgis_geojson.php in your webserver.

Call the geojson in your Leafleat JavaScript code with the following get parameters:

```
postgis_geojson.php?geotable=WTGs_All&geomfield=the_geom
```

This will return all the features, with all the attributes in EPSG:4326

Comment: Should I call the geojson this way? var geojson = L.geojson('conn.php?geotable=WTGs_All&geomfield=the_geom',
 {
 style: style,
 maxZoom: 6,
 onEachFeature: onEachFeature
 }).addTo(map);

Comment: Yes, have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

You have unnecessarily changed the keys ($_GET['...']) for parameters. They should be left in original state, as this script is designed to read their values from the query string. The code should be:

```
# Retrive URL variables
if (empty($_GET['geotable'])) {
    echo "missing required parameter: <i>geotable</i>";
    exit;
} else
    $geotable = $_GET['geotable'];

if (empty($_GET['geomfield'])) {
    echo "missing required parameter: <i>geomfield</i>";
    exit;
} else
    $geomfield = $_GET['geomfield'];
```

And the request:

```
postgis_geojson.php?geotable=WTGs_All&geomfield=the_geom
```